# Ruby time class monkeypatching

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am monkey patching time class to have a instance function TimeZone

```
class Time
  def in_indian_time
    puts "I am Time"
    self.in_time_zone('New Delhi')
  end
end
```

Here in console when I am typing

```
> Time.now.in_indian_time
> I am Time
> => Fri, 18 Jul 2014 17:42:27 IST +05:30
```

But if I am doing it using active record

```
>     u  = User.first
>     u.created_at.in_indian_time
>     I am Time
>     => Fri, 18 Jul 2014 13:14:45 UTC +00:00
```

Here why with Time.now it is giving IST and with active record date is is giving UTC.

Comment: See this - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html . You have to config it in Rails explicitly. and Look also - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-active-record

Comment: Ok got it 'in_time_zone' changes time but not time zone, right?